# How to tell a Performance Monitor Data Collector Set to regularly generate Reports?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitoring, performance-counters, report

In a nutshell, my goal is to do a **long-time recording of several performance counters**.

My steps I took until now were:

Some days ago I've created several user-defined Data Collector Sets in Windows Server 2008 R2 like this:

[image]

I've configured a schedule that never expires:

[image]

Now what I've expected is that this forces the Performance Monitor to automatically generate reports on a daily basis.

What actually happened is that one report was immediately generated when I set up the Data Collector Sets and another one was created as kind of "pending". No new reports were created after that:

[image]

The first report looks normally, the second report stays in "Collecting..." state forever:

[image]

I've read through MSDN/TechNet and simply cannot figure out what I'm either misunderstanding or doing wrong.

Also, I've carefully checked the Event Log and found no relevant entries so far.

**My question therefore is:**

How to configure my Data Collector Sets to records performance counters for several days?

Comment: Amazingly this is still ambiguous today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your stop condition.  In order to have a report for each day (rather than one report for multiple days), I'm pretty sure you would need to restart your performance counter.  The counter will run for as long as you have it configured for in stop condition.  Check the `logman` command for automating via command line.

Comment: Thanks, @floyd. I have _no_ stop conditions configured. Am I understanding it correct that I have to configure a stop condition to get what I want (i.e. a report a day)?

Comment: That is how I understand it.  I have never used the scheduled tab, and have always configured it via stop condition tab.  Ie. you right click start counter, it runs until it hits its stop condition. Whether that be 30 minutes, 5 days, 6 months etc.  I see what your trying to do, which may be possible, I just have never successfully configured it that way.